# Prove $\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i^*\leq\frac{f(\hat{x})-f^*}{\underset{i=1,\ldots,m}{\min}(-g_i(\hat{x}))}$

Tags: solution-verification, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

> Consider the primal problem (P)
> (P) $f^*$= $\min f(x)$
> s.t $g_i(x)\le0$
> where $f,g_i$ are convex functoin and suppose there exists $\hat{x}$ such that $g_i(\hat{x})<0$ and (P) is bounded from below ($f^*>-\infty$).
> Consider the dual problem given by $\max\{q(\lambda):\lambda\in dom(q)\}$
> where $q(\lambda)=\min_xL(x,\lambda),dom(q)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^m_+:q(\lambda)>-\infty\}$,Let $\lambda^*$be an optimal solution of the dual problem.
> Prove
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i^*\leq\frac{f(\hat{x})-f^*}{\underset{i=1,\ldots,m}{\min}(-g_i(\hat{x}))}$$

From the the information that $\lambda^*$ is optimal solution of (D) we can deduce from that and from farkas non-linear lemma :\
$$f^*\leq q(\lambda^*)=\underset{x}{\min}\{f(x)+\sum_i\lambda_i^*g_i(x)\}$$\
Because we take the minimal $x$ at $q(x^*)$ if we take $\hat{x}$ we only increase the value therefore:\
$\underset{x}{\min}\{f(x)+\sum_i\lambda_i^*g_i(x)\}\leq f(\hat{x})+\sum_i\lambda_i^*g_i(\hat{x})\to f^*\leq f(\hat{x})+\sum_i\lambda_i^*g_i(\hat{x})\iff f(\hat{x})-f^*\geq -\sum_i\lambda_i^*g_i(\hat{x})\geq \underset{i=1,\ldots,m}{\min}(-g_i(\hat{x}))\sum_i\lambda_i^*$\
Therefore we get $f(\hat{x})-f^*\geq\underset{i=1,\ldots,m}{\min}(-g_i(\hat{x}))\sum_i\lambda_i^*$ as desired.\

Comment: Should the inequality in "$f^*\leq q(\lambda^*)$" not be the other way around (weak duality theorem)? And what is your question?

Comment: I've used the non-linear farkas' lemma and I fixed something in the last sentence.

Comment: I am still wondering if this is a question :)

Comment: It's more solution verificatoin :)

Comment: There are two issues: the use of 'min', for example, what happens when you use $f(x) = e^x$ without any constraints; and the minus sign in $-g_i$ seems to appear out of nowhere.

Comment: for the minus i had a mistake overthere,When I changes sides we get the minus sign(tell me now if it's ok).
and for the min I didn't understand

Comment: The minus sign is good now. If $f(x) = e^x$, then (P) is bounded below but does not have an optimal solution so $f^*$ and $q$ are not defined.

Comment: I think it is defined but we cant use the weak/strong duality

Comment: @LinAlg do you have a way to fix the proof if you think it's wrong?

Comment: if the functions are not closed, what you are trying to prove is false because min and max do not necessarily exist